# Error 'ReactDOM' is defined but never used no-unused

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Can someone explain why I am getting the error 'ReactDOM' is defined but never used  no-unused when I run this code?
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

```
ReactDOM.render(
    <h1>Hello world</h1>,
    document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Comment: It's not an error - it's an ESLint warning. I don't know why you're getting it but [you can turn it off if you need to](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-unused-vars).

Comment: You haven't really provided enough code for anyone to say why you have a warning about `ReactDOM` not being used.

Comment: https://github.com/yannickcr/eslint-plugin-react/issues/387 perhaps?

Comment: I'm just learning react right now, so that's literally all my code. The h1 won't show up in the browser either

Comment: Yes, but you wouldn't be getting an ESLint error if you weren't using ESLint. Is this an app created with create-react-app? Is it a stand-alone script in an HTML file to which you've simply added the react/react-dom scripts? There's a lot of information missing from your question, and we can't solve those kind of issues.

Comment: It was created with create-react-app and the only thing I did in the folder was replace the files in the src folder with this index.js file.

Comment: Maybe add React and ReactDOM to the globals prop in `.eslint` in your root folder.